# How to add object to external JSON file with a button-click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Goodday fellow programmer,

I'm having trouble adding an object to my JSON file. I'm using jQuery. 
My javascript file:

```html
$('#addchallenge').click(function()
{
    //hardcoded challenge
    var addchallenge =
    {
        "achievementname": "I am an achievement who want to be added to the list",
        "points": "50",
        "comment": "guess who has been a nasty achievement to add"
    }

    $.getJSON("../json/package.json", function (data)
    {
        $.each(data.allachievements, function ()
        {
            //very suspicious line here:
            this["achievementlist"].push(addchallenge);
        });
    });
});
```

My external JSON file:

```html
{
"allachievements":[
    {
      "name": "list of all achievements",
      "achievementlist": [
        {
          "achievementname": "first achievement",
          "points": "30",
          "comment": "the first achievement to achieve"
        },
        {
          "achievementname": "second achievement",
          "points": "-90",
          "comment": "is worth a negative amout of points"
        },
        {
          "achievementname": "aaand the 3th achievement",
          "points": "30",
          "comment": "do you already have achievement 1 and 2?"
        }]
    }]
}
```

How could the addchallenge data be added into my JSON file?

Do I need to parse my JSON data, add my challenge to add, then stringify it back?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You cant directly manipulate the JSON file - Writing, deleting etc.

However, you could write some backend code thats capable of this.

If you simply want to temporally add an achievement, you can parse in your JSON file into a variable and then manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the JSON file only with client side code. You need some server side code.

I would recommend you to use [post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/).

**EDIT:** 
I actually found this: [How to : edit an external json file in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869615/how-to-edit-an-external-json-file-in-javascript)

So, current post may be considered a duplicate...

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to write into a file using jquery?
if so please check the following url:
[Read/write to file using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582268/read-write-to-file-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `this`, the context. Inside of the callback you are passing to `$.each` iterator, `this` is not what you think it is.

> jQuery.each( array, callback )
>
> *callback*
>
> Type: Function( String propertyName, Object valueOfProperty )
>   The function that will be executed on every object.

I would change your `code` like this:

```
$.getJSON("../json/package.json", function (data)
{
    $.each(data.allachievements, function (key, value)
    {
        value["achievementlist"] = value["achievementlist"] || [];
        value["achievementlist"].push(addchallenge);
    });
});
```